# problema num aplicativo maven + JSF

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2.2, maven

Estou tentando seguir uma apostila mas quando faço o procedimento de Acessar as propriedades do projeto e encontre o menu lateral Project Facets aparece a janela no anexo e, seguida eu marco a altenativa como mostra na figura JavaServer Faces

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o eclipse orienta para clicar na área em destaque com o nome de

further configuration available

o que consigo entender é que ele quer que eu adicione a biblioteca do jsf manualmente.

esse não é o procedimento comum.

inclusive já adicionei a biblioteca pelo práprio Maven

o que somente eu quero é marca a opção JavaServer Faces é da OK seguinda a apostila.

como eu faço para resolver esse problema?

o projeto que estou criando é um projeto Maven.

quando eu executo o aplicativo mesmo com o problema ele gera essa mensagem

An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Mas o foco do livro é o uso do Maven? Se for bastaria usar o archetype adequado ou colocar as referências no pom.xml. O que eu acho que está acontecendo é que você está usando uma implementação jsf embarcada no seu projeto e não está fazendo um 'update' no seu repositório maven.

Comment: qual seria o archetype adequado para um projeto Maven  + JSF?

Comment: Não sei, depende muito. Como você está aprendendo eu sugiro que use o blank e depois clique com o botão direito sobre o projeto - configuration - Add JSF Capabilities (Ou algo assim).

Comment: eu não tenho essa opção no meu eclipse de Add JSF ou tipo do algo parecido.

Comment: É complicado ajudar pois o problema não é pontual. Tenta ler este link: http://www.infobase.com.br/criando-projeto-jsf-maven-eclipse/

Comment: a versão do eclipse Luna retirou essa opção, já tinha visto esse site.

Comment: dá uma olhada aqui http://www.guj.com.br/26245-problemas-com-maven--jsf

Comment: Se sua intenção é aprender, eu sugiro tentar com o NetBeans, ele tem integração nativa com maven, e é bem mais amigável para iniciantes.

Comment: @wladyband Então sugiro que responda sua própria pergunta e marque como resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Ola,
Boa Noite, bom consegui resolver o mesmo problema fazendo o download da biblioteca do mojarra apenas, usando o link destacado na imagem abaixo!

[image: para acessar tal janela basta clicar no erro abaixo da lista da janela project facets]